# Is there anyway that if I click Generate it gives me 3 tokens instead of only one?

Tags: javascript, passwords

I'm trying to create a login form with a password generator so my problem is that I want to generate 3 tokens, What I have been attempting to do generates only 1 token per click. So instead of only 1 password token that will be generated is there any way that 3 password tokens will be generated instead?

```js
const CHARS =
  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

const randomCharacter = (chars) => () => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];

const generatePassword = (chars) => (length) => () => [...Array(length)].map(randomCharacter(chars)).join("");

const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");
const generatePasswordChars = generatePassword(CHARS);
const generatePasswordChars12 = generatePasswordChars(12);

document.querySelector("#generate-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  passwordInput.value = generatePasswordChars12();
});

document.querySelector("#copy-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText(passwordInput.value)
    .catch(() =>
      console.error("Can't copy (you need to open this in its own window).")
    );
});
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Random Password Generator</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Create password" id="password" readonly />
    <div class="actions">
      <button id="generate-button">Generate</button>
      <button id="copy-button">Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" id="passcode" readonly />
    <div class="actions">
      <button id="enter-button">Enter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant you simply call `generatePassword` thrice, each with a different `input`?

Comment: Or change the input to a text area. Create three different passwords, concatenate them with a line-break (`\n`), and add that string the text area's value.